# AWS Lightsail how to install packages to be available to all users on the instance

Tags: yum, amazon-lightsail

The default user is `ec2-user`, I also created another user called `admin`. The instance is OS-only, no templates are installed.

I'm trying to install nginx, nodejs and git, I logged in as `ec2-user` and did:
`sudo yum install git`. `git` works for `ec2-user`, but when I log in with `admin` it doesn't.

How do I go about installing the packages more globally so all users have access? Also I assume I would have similar issues with where a `www` or `html` folder lives, would I put that folder in `/usr/share/nginx/` to be available to all users?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the admin user to the sudoers file.

1. Log in as ec2-user
2. Run 'sudo visudo'
3. Add the admin id
4. Exit

You should now be able to use sudo when logged in as admin.